# stuck on best approach for media query on this layout

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

I am trying to learn responsive design. I am building a website and one of the pages is a portfolio. I set up the following mockup of how I would lay out this page. it is a very stripped down version of course. I cannot seem to apply the proper queries so that this format would look ok on a widescreen desktop, an ipad and lets say a mobile phone. I started the 1st query but it isnt working of course and also know if that is the best size for a common widescreen desktop.

Can anybody get me started on how to apply that to this page? Im going to continue on tutorials but need a kick start here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
<style type="text/css">
@media screen and (max-width:1080px) {
    #main {
        width: 960px;
    }
}
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin:0;
}

#main {
    width: 1080px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 860px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.box {
    background-color: #CCC;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.box_last {
    background-color: #CCC;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.box_bottom {
    background-color: #CCC;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;

}
.box_last_bottom {
        background-color: #CCC;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;

}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box_last"></div>

  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box_last"></div>

  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box_last"></div>

  <div class="box_bottom"></div>
  <div class="box_bottom"></div>
  <div class="box_bottom"></div>
  <div class="box_bottom"></div>
  <div class="box_last_bottom"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I find it common to use negative margins on the outside most div so that the inside div are can have positive margins (to give them spacing between them) and yet there is no space for the first/last element.  I can explain better if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code the `#main` from the media query block is getting overwritten. You have to put your media queries at the very bottom of your CSS

```css
#main {
    width: 1080px;
    ...
}

@media screen and (max-width:1080px) {
    #main {
        width: 960px;
    }

    .box {
        width: 200px;
        ...
    }
}
```

And then for a smaller screen

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #main {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .box {
        width: 50%;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying with that. I have applied the code but still nothing happens?

Comment: I've set up a quick fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Aw2yG/ just resize the rendered output window to see how the boxes changing

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I really appreciate your help sincerely. Looks like I missed the one step of moving the media query below the styles.   Hey I just saw your website in your profile. I am going to email you about possible development work. Thanks again!